# Retrieve the latest entry to a document Firestore flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm wondering how to retrieve the latest entry into a document in firebase using flutter?

I can see that orderBy can be used on collections which would retrieve the latest document but can't see anything to specific entries.

My data is as follows:
[image]

Current code is as follows, but obviously doesn't return the latest.

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getData() async {
    var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('USER_TABLE')
        .doc(currentUser!.uid)
        .get();
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a timestamp field to your document, then do an orderBy timestamp in descending order, then do limit(1) - that gives you the latest value inserted.